# Pairing collection elements in F#

Tags: collections, f#

I am looking at the list of collection functions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-collection-types

but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a list of elements:

```
[ 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8 ]
```

and I am looking for something like this:

```
[ 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8 ]
|> List.iterPair (fun x y -> ())
```

where it would pass me:

```
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
```

Is there a way to do this with the built-in functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation is commonly known as `pairwise`:

And indeed, there is `List.pairwise`, which returns a tuple.

```
list 
|> List.pairwise
|> List.iter(fun (x, y) -> printfn "%d %d" x y)
```

Gives your expected output.

A more general way to think of it is:

```
List.zip (list |> List.skip 1) list
```

As pairwise is unavailable in Linq:

```
items.Zip(items.Skip(1), (a, b) => a, b)
```

Of course, it would be more efficient with a `scan`, but this is more readable.